# Dump All Images Possible On a Laptop Motherboard

Tags: firmware, uefi, imaging

In relation to another [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/274384/laptop-repair-vs-evil-maid) I wanted to ask, supposing I pulled the drives from a laptop, and the GPU/CPU/TPM/RAM are soldered on the mother board (along with lots of other random chips). ***What software ("images") persists on the mother board*** (firmware, ROM's, UEFI, BIOS, stuff on random IC's, etc.), ***and, how much of it can be accessed at different levels?***:

Level 0: "Images" that can be extracted using the laptop itself (when booted) using general tools or inexpensive specialty software. Also common pieces of hardware may be nessiary such as USB drives, it may also be nessisary to flash an OS to a USB drive, such as [luv-yocto](https://github.com/intel/luv-yocto) or a [fork](https://github.com/prakhya/luv_sai) thereof.

Level 1: Some hardware necessary, but nothing a casual tinkerer may have laying around, eg. Raspberry Pi, Micro-controller Programmer, a resistor, a flash drive, multi-meter, etc. Nothing should need to be de-soldered from the board, and nothing prohibitively expensive

Level 2: Removing the restrictions on level 1 may require the use of a JTAG (expensive hardware or more "hard core" hardware) or desoldering components off the mother board

Level 3+: You have institutional resources.

The point would be to audit these "images" and check them, similar to how SecureBoot might

After a little research I found *some possible* software that might help:

1. [Integrity Measurement Architecture](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-ima/files/ima-evm-utils/)
2. [luv-yocto](https://github.com/intel/luv-yocto) or a [fork](https://github.com/prakhya/luv_sai)
3. [TrouSerS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/trousers/)
4. [chipsec](https://chipsec.github.io/)

Though I don't know if any of these will do what I want to do to the extent I would like too or not

Comment: It boils down to exactly the same as your previous question: if you can't trust the hardware, you can't trust it. If your adversary can create custom firmware at will *and* have physical access to your device for some stretch of time, the game is up. There's nothing you can do. Neither to prevent it nor detect it.